# Asynchronous Read/Writing with libraw1394

Tags: linux-kernel, firewire

I'm trying to get two computers to communicate with each other over firewire. Both of the computers are running Ubuntu 9.10 and both have read/write access to the /dev/raw1394 node. I'm using [firecontrol](http://firecontrol.sourceforge.net/) to quickly test sending read/write requests. If I can get it to work with firecontrol, I should be able to figure out how to do the same in my code.

On computer A, I do this:

> computerA $ ./commander
>   Work Now
>   Copyright (C) 2002-2007 by Manfred Weihs 
>   This software comes with absolutely no warranty.
>
> No adapter specified!
>   successfully got handle
>   current generation number (driver): 1
>   1 card(s) found
>     nodes on bus:  2, card name: ohci1394
>   using adapter 0
>   found: 2 nodes on bus, local ID is 1, IRM is 1
>   current generation number (adapter): 7
>
> entering command mode
>   Type 'help' for more information!
>   Command: w . 0 0 0xDE
>   insufficient arguments for operation!
>   Command: w . 0 0 2 0xDe
>   writing to  node 0, bus 1023, offset 000000000000 2 bytes:
>   00 DE
>   write succeeded.
>   Ack code: complete

Since computer A is on node 1, I send to node 0. Then I go to computer B and read from node 0 and get this:

> computerB $ ./commander
>   Copyright (C) 2002-2007 by Manfred Weihs 
>   This software comes with absolutely no warranty.
>
> No adapter specified!
>   successfully got handle
>   current generation number (driver): 1
>   1 card(s) found
>     nodes on bus:  2, card name: ohci1394
>   using adapter 0
>   found: 2 nodes on bus, local ID is 0, IRM is 1
>   current generation number (adapter): 9
>
> entering command mode
>   Type 'help' for more information!
>   Command: r . 0 0 1
>   reading from node 0, bus 1023, offset 000000000000 1 bytes
>   read failed.
>   Ack code: pending; Response code: address error

I'm using the same offset for both of them. What am I doing wrong and how am I supposed to read/write from/to firewire nodes?

I have these same problems when I try and use raw1394 in my own code.